# Padre for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, perl, ide

Im trying to install Padre (Perl IDE) on Ubuntu using command `sudo apt-get install padre`

But I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package padre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'padre' has no installation candidate
```

Why is Padre removed from repositories?

Comment: look for it with: `apt search padre` if you don't see it then you can't get via `apt`

Comment: Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

Comment: that means not in the official repos perhaps a third party might have it

Comment: I was following http://padre.perlide.org/download.html

Comment: u can see that the highest support there is Ubuntu 10...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed in 16.04. The [publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/padre/+publishinghistory) says:

> Deleted on 2016-03-10 by Martin Pitt
>   (From Debian) ROM; RC buggy and dead upstream; Debian bug #814005

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by muru padre is no longer installable by the normal way in Ubuntu 16.04

However, there is an easy workaround, which worked for me.

From their official site download the windows installation file and install it using wine program loader. It works perfectly fine.